# Averaging har files

Tags: performance-testing, har, web-performance

When trying to analyze a website's performance, it is useful to run a monitoring session multiple times, since wait times and receive times can vary randomly.

I couldn't find a practical way to then average several Http ARchive (har) files together into one.

Any recommendation ?

Comment: I think a better way to go about it would be to take the average / median run  (in terms of load time, etc) instead of averaging all the times together..